# how to query MARGIN / ISOLATED wallet balances using Binance API?

Tags: binance

For a SPOT wallet, I can get all balances of the wallet by making a request to `https://api.binance.com/sapi/v1/capital/config/getall` (with correct API key, signature, etc.).

How can I query MARGIN / ISOLATED balances? I don't see an obvious answer in Binance API docs.

Answer (score 2):

In the terms of Binance, each isolated balance is a separate account like spot, cross margin, or futures.
For query isolated balances you can use this endpoint
`GET /sapi/v1/margin/isolated/account`

For details please read the docs.
https://binance-docs.github.io/apidocs/spot/en/#query-isolated-margin-account-info-user_data

Comment: Thank you, it works! I wish they've used the same naming and output format for spot and margin/isolated APIs.